# JSF: Unable to set null values in h:inputText within ui:repeat

Tags: jsf

Mojarra 2.1.6 / Glassfish 3.1.2

I have something like this

```
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{bean.items}">
  <h:inputText value="#{item.longProperty}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

where Item is an object with a Long property

```
public class Item { 
  private Long longProperty; // + getters/setters
}
```

It works fine as long as I'm setting longProperty to something not-null / non-empty.
When I do that, the null input is ignored and the old value is restored.

Similar results for Dates.

It makes no difference if I eliminate the reference to the var/status from the ui:repeat.  Even explicitly referencing #{bean.items[0].longProperty} fails the same way.

The same exact h:inputText works fine outside of a ui:repeat and null/empty values work just fine.

Additionally, *inside* a ui:repeat, empty strings work ok, if the property is a String rather than an object that requires conversion.

To make it even weirder: if I put a valueChangeEvent on the input, I do see that `event.getNewValue()` returns null when I expect it - yet my setter is called with the old value.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: the fact that you're seeing old values after a submit is indicative of a validation/conversion error, so it's not that weird. My suspicion is that `<ui:repeat>` is essentially a loop construct and it's understandable that it will choke on a null value and cause a conversion error

Comment: except there is no conversion / validation failure.  No exceptions logged and no validation messages - `<h:messages/>` is empty.  And the conversion and validation don't fire on empty fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its a Mojarra / JSF implementation bug with ui:repeat

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1721

Comment: This bug has been closed as Won't Fix. :(

Answer (score 0):

And duplicated now, here (by Roger Kitain):

http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2717

Answer (score 0):

Change `<ui:repeat>` to `<a4j:repeat>` .

```
<a4j:repeat var="item" value="#{bean.items}">
  <h:inputText value="#{item.longProperty}"/>
</a4j:repeat>
```

More info: [Richfaces a4j:repeat](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_repeat.html).

See more about the `<ui:repeat>` bug at [Problem with ui:repeat and NULL values in JSF 2.x](http://blog.oio.de/2013/01/29/problem-with-uirepeat-and-null-values-in-jsf-2-x/).